# Bash Script - Integer expression expected in Azure pipeline

Tags: bash

I am running a pipeline in Azure with the below bash script to echo username and password from a variable group to the pipeline.tfvars file but its giving me the below error:

```
+ '[' $ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME -eq Cloud_AZ01 ']'
/home/vsts/work/_temp/a969a6a0-20k3-8320-2302-26bad13f342.sh: line 19: [: Cloud_AZ01-ActiveDirectory-1-N: integer expression expected
```

This is my code:

```
if [ $ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME -eq 'Cloud-AZ01' ]; then
    echo "NP_user           = \"$(NP_user)\""           >> pipeline.tfvars  
    echo "NP_password     = \"$(NP_password)\""     >> pipeline.tfvars 
   fi
```

Any help be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`-eq` expects 2 integers to be compared for equality. `'Cloud-AZ01'` is clearly a string, you should use `=` to compare strings. from `man [`:

> INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2
>
> INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2
>
> ...
>
> STRING1 = STRING2
>
> the strings are equal

for example:

```
$ if [ "a" -eq "a" ]; then echo "equal!"; fi
-bash: [: a: integer expression expected
$ if [ "a" = "a" ]; then echo "equal!"; fi
equal!
$ if [ 12 -eq 12 ]; then echo "equal!"; fi
equal!
```

I would rewrite the condition as:

```
if [ "$ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME" = "Cloud-AZ01" ]; then
```

Comment: Thank you! this has fixed the integer error but now am getting this below error, even though i have declared the variables in variables.tf

Error: No value for required variable

  on subscriptions/Cloud-AZ01/variables.tf line 1:
   1: variable "NP_user" {

The root module input variable "NP_user" is not set, and has
no default value. Use a -var or -var-file command line argument to provide a
value for this variable.


this is my variable value:
variable "NP_user" {}

Comment: @rayaurelius glad it helped you! unfortunately I'm not familiar with "Azure pipeline" and variables declaration in that environment. the question was specific to integer error and the answer solved the error. I would accept the answer and open another question specific to the new error you are getting providing as many details as possible.